# Как правильно: выбрать из списка или в списке?

Tags: лексика, стилистика

Собственно вопрос вынесен в заголовок. Встречаются оба варианта. Есть ли смысловая разница? В словаре при глаголе "выбрать" дается только предлог **из.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ВЫБРАТЬ**,  св. 1. кого-что. Взять, отобрать.

Это общее значение глагола, может использоваться **с предлогами ИЗ и В.**

Примеры с предлогом В: **выбрать в списке, в задании, в меню.**

**Разница в оттенках значений:**

1) Выбрать **из задания** предложение и записать его в тетрадь ― выбрать предмет и что-то с ним сделать, как-то использовать.

2) Выбрать **в задании** слова с раздельным написанием ― просто отметить эти слова.

**Примеры:**

― Выбрать **в списке** тип графического образа htm, после чего нажать кнопку «Выбрать» ... (2004) // «Информационные технологии», 2004.03.29]

Люди, добившиеся успеха, отличаются не тем, что они хорошо и качественно выполняют свои дела, а тем, что они умеют **выбрать из списка** дел правильные. [Анастасия Чанько.  2008]

Comment: А в чем разница: выбрать салат из меню и выбрать салат в меню?

Comment: Выбрать салат из меню и заказать его. Выбрать (отметить)  несколько салатов в меню и подумать, какой заказыать.